# Issue building tf2_ros on OSX

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, tf2, boost, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running into this problem while trying to build tf2_ros on OSX:

> ==> make -j4 -l4 in '/Users/Yeison/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2_ros'
> Linking CXX shared library
> /Users/Yeison/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2_ros/lib/libtf2_ros.dylib
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Full output: https://gist.github.com/yeison/5244835

I think the following patch is meant to address the issue:
https://github.com/ros/geometry-experimental/pull/6

I'll have to try and pull those changes in locally to test.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59212/issue-building-tf2_ros-on-osx/) by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'll have to try and pull those
> changes in locally to test.

That seems to have worked!

https://github.com/ros/geometry-experimental/pull/6

---

Originally posted by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) with karma: 103 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2013-03-26**:
I just ran into this as well and the fix worked fine! Thx a lot!

**Comment by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on 2013-03-29**:
I'm glad that helped.  Thanks to @WilliamWoodall for that patch.